# apt-get always installs old version of node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I want to install 11.x version of Node.js on my Ubuntu sevrer using apt/apt-get, but it always installs version 8.10.x. Is there a way to install the latest 12.x or 11.x version without using nvm?

I've tried apt-get update, purging nodejs, using commands below:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

None of above helped. I'm still getting an old verion of Node.js

Comment: You might have better luck asking the question on the unix or ubuntu stack exchanges instead of on stackoverflow since they're more oriented towards these types of questions

Comment: Following these commands on my machine installs Node 11.15.0

Comment: Yes, I have also successfully installed latest Node.js on other machines using the curl approach, but this time it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The implementations of languages provided by operating systems tend to lean towards stability within their particular ecosystem (i.e: they play nice with everything else in the repositories). If you wish to use a newer version I recommend [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) which allows you install multiple versions of implementations of various languages including Node.

Comment: Well, both nvm and asdf approaches helped, but I can't get the source of the problem. I've just installed latest version using curl on clean new machine. I have probably accidentally changed the source repository for nodejs, but that is unlikely.

Comment: You probably now have multiple node executables that are conflicting, try `whereis node`